# Owncloud webdav access from php

Tags: php, pear, webdav, owncloud

I'm trying to access my owncloud webdav interface and get the list of files in the root directory from [PEAR WebDAV Client](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_WebDAV_Client/redirected). I'm trying the following:

```
include("HTTP/WebDAV/Client.php");
$client = new HTTP_WebDAV_Client_Stream();

$user="admin";
$pass = "q1w2e3r4";

$dir = "webdavs://".$user.":".$pass."@127.0.0.1:10081/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/";

$stuff = $client->dir_opendir($dir, array());
var_dump($stuff);
var_dump($client->dirfiles);
```

The code print false, false, and when I've tried to debug it, I saw Connection refused error in Socket.php, when it tried to call the function

```
fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 10081, $err, $errstr);
```

It's even more strange since I can access this server and list the directories from [cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/) though. Also I can access the test DAV server with my code by replacing my `$dir` variable:

```
$dir = "webdavs://".$user.":".$pass."@127.0.0.1:10081/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an ugly hack, but if you add something similar to:

```
 var_dump($err->getMessage());
```

to /usr/share/php/HTTP/Request.php on line 739, you should be able to see the most relevant error message. (If that is where Request.php got installed to.)

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a mechanism in place in the underlying HTTP_Request package for raising that specific error message back to the HTTP_WebDAV_Client_Stream code.

Comment: I debuged that to that point and further and found that it's `Connection refused` message. That didn't help much though.

Comment: It's likely then that the username/password is incorrect. If not, perhaps the server is expecting those credentials to be encrypted to some form and they are not. I know nothing about the webdav protocol itself so I can't say for sure, but that may be likely it.

Comment: yeah, I think your guess about the encryption is right. It would be great to watch how cadaver established the proper connection.

Comment: Try using something like wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff what happens with some other client connecting in.

Comment: I decided to try Pydio instead - it has REST API for accessing the files